# How to know how many views are in the Navigator?

Tags: flutter

I want to know how many views are in the 'Navigator', but `Navigator().pages.length` has no effect,

I found that: 'To use this API, an [onPopPage] callback must also be provided to properly', and I did that `Navigator(onPopPage: callback).pages.length`, it has no effect yet.

Comment: Are you talking about general views which can be accessed via the Navigator or all views which are in the history of the navigator?

Comment: The latter,I can't get how many views in the history of the navigator

Comment: `Navigator().pages.length` should work for this case. What is the output? Also could you provide the code which you are using to generate the routes?